# Generate random AES key, convert it to string and back to byte (Python)

Tags: python, string, cryptography, byte, aes

my problem is the following.
For an AES encryption I generate a random key of size 32.

```
random_key = os.urandom(32)
```

**Output: b'\xf3\xd9\x9a\n>\x99-k\xecv@VG\xecK\x9c\xbf\xcb\xae!\xb8&}\x01:\x9f0\xf1\x04\xb4\xd7\x81'**

I need to store this key as an string. So i convert it to a string as follows.

```
key_string = random_key.decode('latin-1')
```

**Output: óÙ**

**>-kìv@VGìK¿Ë®!¸&}☺:♦´×**

I use 'latin-1', because when I use 'utf-8' or anything else I get an error message. The string has a lot of spaces as well.

Later on I convert this string back to a byte string.

```
key_byte = key_string.encode()
```

**Output: b'\xc3\xb3\xc3\x99\xc2\x9a\n>\xc2\x99-k\xc3\xacv@VG\xc3\xacK\xc2\x9c\xc2\xbf\xc3\x8b\xc2\xae!\xc2\xb8&}\x01:\xc2\x9f0\xc3\xb1\x04\xc2\xb4\xc3\x97\xc2\x81'**

As you can see the first byte code and the second dont match at all. Not even in the size.
I guess its becuase of the decoding method.

Comment: The default argument for `encode` is `"utf-8"` (if I remember correctly). You need to explicitly specify you want to encode using `"latin-1"`

Comment: Okay, yes true it worked. Thanks for the help. Kind of stupid of me :D

Comment: The typical method for storing passwords as a string is to hex encode it.   byte_string.hex() converts it to a hex string.  bytes.fromhex(string) converts it back to bytes.  This gives you a string that is easily human-readable, while latin-1 gives you a string of gibberish.

Comment: Converting arbitrary binary data to a string with a charset encoding (like UTF-8) generally corrupts the data. Here [binary-to-text encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) must be used, such as hex encoding. An alternative with a higher efficiency is Base64.